# Selecting records by group each having the max date respectively

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, having-clause

I have three tables of concern and a query which generates the following output from them, where each field is prepended by a letter representing the table of origin for demonstration purposes. What I would like instead, is a report with only the most recent data, i.e. I want only the row returned with the MAX(EntryDate), but I can't figure out how to accomplish this. I've tried, `HAVING`, aggregates, etc, but with no success. Either my approach is wrong, or I'm missing something syntactically.

```
s.ID    r.FirstID    m.ID   m.PartNum     m.Revision     r.EntryDate
26      42           13     NULL          A              2012-03-25 15:32:00
26      42           17     820044444     B              2012-03-27 09:48:00
26      42           14     820056789     C              2012-03-28 12:19:00
```

Desired Result:

```
s.ID    r.FirstID    m.ID   m.PartNum     m.Revision     r.EntryDate
26      42           14     820056789     C              2012-03-28 12:19:00
```

For a little additional background, the r.FirstID represents a grouping of records all related to each other, so **for each grouping** I wish to return only the record with the most recent data.

Here is my query that I have so far:

```
select s.ID,r.FirstID,m.ID,m.PartNum,m.Revision,r.EntryDate from StatusLog s
    left join (select FirstID,PartInfoID from Request where PartInfoID is not null group by FirstID,PartInfoID) r on s.FirstID= r.FirstID
    --required filtering here? Or move this extra join to the inner query?
    left join PartInfo m on r.PartInfoID = m.ID
```

I'm using SQL Server for my DBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way will be to use `ROW_NUMBER()` (and I am using a `CTE` for simplicity). Let me know if you need me to explain what is happening here :)

```
WITH myCTE
AS
(
    SELECT s.ID AS sID, r.FirstID, m.ID AS mID, m.PartNum, m.Revision, 
        r.EntryDate, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
            (PARTITION BY r.FirstID ORDER BY r.EntryDate DESC) AS RowNumber
    FROM StatusLog s
        LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT FirstID, PartInfoID 
            FROM Request 
            WHERE PartInfoID IS NOT NULL 
            GROUP BY FirstID,PartInfoID
        ) AS r 
            ON s.FirstID= r.FirstID
        LEFT JOIN PartInfo m 
            ON r.PartInfoID = m.ID
)
SELECT sID,FirstID,mID,PartNum,Revision,EntryDate
FROM myCTE 
WHERE RowNumber = 1;
```

Comment: No sir, this only works for a specific case. Please re-read my question. I have bolded the key point. I need it to return a result set, **one row for EACH group** as determined by the `r.FirstID` field.

Comment: @Chiramisu OK, fixed :) I just had to remove the s.ID from the ROW_NUMBER() GROUP BY. This should work now. I also noticed that my ORDER BY was not correct, so changed it to DESC :)

Comment: I don't think you can use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (GROUP BY`. I think you meant `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY` right?

Comment: @Justin: SHouldn't that be `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY r.FirstID ...`

Comment: @arion Oops, haha, since it is a grouping action, that is what was floating in my head :) Fixed now

Comment: I had to take a different approach, but hopefully this answer will be helpful to someone. It certainly demonstrates a powerful concept in SQL Server. Thanks. :)

Comment: The key is that you need the "WHERE RowNumber=1". I was trying to figure out why mine wasn't working until I noticed I missed that part. Incase someone else struggles to implement this same thing.